# regular expression for 2 string arguments having numeric values with range constraint

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to validate console input arguments. User can pass only 2 arguments separated by Space.

1. First argument should be between 1 to 100
2. Second argument should be between 1 to 750.

I need a regular expression to validate the input. Please help.

Comment: You would probably be better off not using regex for this.

Comment: Rather than a regex I recommend to use `String.Split` and then `int.TryParse`

Comment: `try { int arg1 = int.Parse(args[0]); int arg2 = int.Parse(args[1]); } catch { Console.WriteLine("bad args"); }` (and then check ranges, of course)

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's bad practice to catch exceptions as part of the program logic. Better to use bools and `TryParse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description

this regex will match 1-100 space 1-750

`^\b([1-9][0-9]?|100)\b\s+\b([1-9][0-9]?|[1-6][0-9]{2}|7[0-4][0-9]|750)\b$`

[image]

## Expanded

- `^` match the start of the string
- `\b` match the word boundary
- `(` open capture group 1

  - `[1-9]` match any single digit not including zero followed by
  - `[0-9]?` match any single digit or no digit
  - `|` or
  - `100` match the number one hundred
  - `)` close the capture group 1
- `\b\s+\b` require a word break, space, and word break.
- `(` start capture group 2

  - `[1-9]` match any single digit not including zero followed by
  - `[0-9]?` match any single digit or no digit
  - `|` or
  - `[1-6]` match any digits 1 thru 6 followed by
  - `[0-9]{2}` match two of any digits
  - `|` or
  - `7` match a seven followed by
  - `[0-4]` match digits 0 thru 4 followed by
  - `[0-9]` match any single digit
  - `|` or
  - `750` match the number seven hundred and fifty
  - `)` close the capture group
- `\b$` require a word break and end of string.

Comment: This is awesome way to explain. it will be great if you can refer some regex basics with example

Comment: I updated the answer with a step by step explanation of what's happening inside the expression. You can also find a wealth of information on regular expressions over at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Comment: Aren't the `\b` redundant?

Comment: In this form they are redundant because we have anchored the start and end of the string. However this being a question and answer site, input and output sample text are usually watered down for simplicity. If this expression where re-purposed and either the `^` or the `$` where removed then the expression may potentially not match as expected

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a pattern like this:

```
^(1|[1-9]\d|100)\s+(1|[1-9]\d|[1-6]\d\d|7[0-5]\d)$
```

However, you are probably better off verifying the inputs via normal integer comparison:

```
int int1, int2;
if (int.TryParse(param1, out int1) && int.TryParse(param2, out int2))
{
    if (int1 >= 1 && int1 <= 100 && int2 >= 1 && int2 <= 750)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The regex doesn't work (try 485 for example), and it should contain `^` and `$` to avoid leading and trailing garbage

Comment: @JuliánUrbano You are correct on both points. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I rather recommend not using regex but something like this:

```
int a=0,b=0;    
if(args.Length != 2){
  // not 2 arguments
}else{
   if(!int.TryParse(args[0], out a) || !int.TryParse(args[1], out b)){
      // not numbers
   }else{
      if(a < 1 || a > 100 || b < 1 || b > 750){
         // out of ranges
      }else{
         // everything fine
      }
   }
}
```

and you'll have your numbers right there.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, regex isn't the best option, but if you really want to use it, this seems to work...

```
^(?:100|[1-9]\d?) (?:[1-7](?:[0-4]\d|50)|[1-9]\d?)$
```